# Flutter Bluetooth Arduino

Tags: flutter, arduino, bluetooth

I am trying to build an app that sends a simple string (just to numbers e.g. 12;16) to an arduino with hc 05 module via bluetooth and the arduino sends a string back, too.
I just wanted to ask you if the flutter_blue or the flutter_bluetooth_serial package is better in my case.

Comment: I am using flutter_bluetooth_serial plugin in this project because it has a lot more features and gives much greater control over the Bluetooth connection while communicating with other devices.  https://blog.codemagic.io/creating-iot-based-flutter-app/

Comment: HC-05 is a Bluetooth Classic (2.0) module.  [Flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) is a BLE package so you can't use it. Use the serial  one.